# nvidia-smi gpu-util meaning

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, nvidia

I am new to learn how to use GPU. I've been searching for the answers of the meaning about GPU-Util when using nvidia-smi, but I haven't get enough answers.

I attached the png file about nvidia-smi and my question is below:

[image: nvidia-smi]

As you can see, my current GPU-util is 100% and my GPU memory usage is 5838MiB and total GPU memory is 5941MiB. If I add the another process 'A' that uses 50MiB on GPU memory, will the process 'A' be pending because GPU-Util is already 100%? Otherwise, will the process 'A' be proceeding because there is enough gpu memory to run the process 'A'?